как правильно протестировать запрос через rtk query?
Хочу протестировать запрос, но получаю ошибку. Пробовал замокать, но пока что не получается. Можете подсказать как правильно это сделать, чтобы можно было протестировать запрос useSendMassageMutation.
Error:
(0 , _requestApi.useSendMassageMutation) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
TypeError: (0 , _requestApi.useSendMassageMutation) is not a function or its return value is not iterable


useSendMassageMutation from requestApi:
let [sendMessage, {
        data: requestsSendMessage, error: errorSendMessage, isError: isErrorSendMessage,  isLoading: loadingSendMassage,
    }] = useSendMessageMutation();

RequestApi:
export const requestApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'requestApi',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    tagTypes: ['request'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({...})


jest.mock('./../../../../redux/entities/requestApi/requestApi', () => ({
    requestApi: {
        reducerPath: 'requestApi',
        reducer: () => ({}),
        middleware: jest.fn(),
        useSendMassageMutation: jest.fn(() => [
            jest.fn(), 
            {
                data: null,
                error: null,
                isError: false,
                isLoading: false,
            },
        ]),
    },
}));

describe('renders contacts', () => {
    test('render com[onents', () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConstactUs />
            </Provider>
        );
        expect(screen.getByText(/Форма обратной связи/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше имя:/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByLabelText(/Ваш email:/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше сообщение:/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /Отправить/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
        screen.debug()
    })

    test('forms check', () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConstactUs classname="test-classname" />
            </Provider>
        );
        // получаем поля
        const nameInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше имя:/i)
        const emailInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваш email:/i)
        const messageInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше сообщение:/i)

        // меняем данные
        fireEvent.change(nameInp, { target: { value: 'Test name' } });
        fireEvent.change(emailInp, {target:{value:'email'}})
        fireEvent.change(messageInp, {target:{value:'message'}})
        // проверяем изменения
        expect(nameInp).toHaveValue('Test name')
        expect(emailInp).toHaveValue('email');
        expect(messageInp).toHaveValue('message')
        screen.debug();
    })

    test('send form', () => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConstactUs classname="test-classname" />
            </Provider>
        );

        const nameInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше имя:/i)
        const emailInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваш email:/i)
        const messageInp = screen.getByLabelText(/Ваше сообщение:/i)
        const sendBtn = screen.getByText(/Отправить/i)

        fireEvent.change(nameInp, { target: { value: 'Test name' } });
        fireEvent.change(emailInp, {target:{value:'email'}})
        fireEvent.change(messageInp, {target:{value:'message'}})


        fireEvent.click(sendBtn)


    })
})


Измените структуру мокирования: Вам нужно мокировать хук напрямую, а не через объект requestApi
